# Array as property. Looking for simpler way to fill an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am pretty new to C# and I see a lot of code where I'm not quite familiar with the syntax. So I was wondering if there's some simpler way of doing what I did here:

I have a class with various properties and functions. One of them is `public int gettypeforitem(int i)` which returns an integer.
I want to define a property of type `int[]` that returns an array of the types of all items.

I come from C++, so the following code seems logic to me, but I was wondering if there's a more "straight forward" way in doing this in C#.
Thank you!

```
public int[] type
{
      get
      {
            List<int> _list = new List<int>();
            for(uint i=0; i<NumberOfItems;i++)
               _list.Add(gettypeforitem(i));
            return _list.ToArray();
      }
}
```

Comment: Just as a comment for the answers that are provided below and since you said you are new to C#.. make sure that when using the answers provided, you include the `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 20):

LINQ is the way forward here, I'd say:

```
public int[] Types => Enumerable.Range(0, NumberOfItems)
                                .Select(i => GetTypeForItem(i))
                                .ToArray();
```

I've changed the names to follow .NET naming conventions, and this is using C# 6's expression-bodied property syntax.

As this is doing a relatively large amount of work for a property - generating a new array every call, for a start - you might want to consider making it a method instead:

```
public int[] GetTypes() => Enumerable.Range(0, NumberOfItems)
                                     .Select(i => GetTypeForItem(i))
                                     .ToArray();
```

As noted in comments elsewhere, you *may* be able to use a method group conversion for the argument to the `Select` method:

```
public int[] GetTypes() => Enumerable.Range(0, NumberOfItems)
                                     .Select(GetTypeForItem)
                                     .ToArray();
```

The exact rules for when method group conversions are valid as arguments always elude me, so I won't try to summarise them here. (They've changed over time, too.)

Comment: This looks very promising. Although I ran into a problem since my `GetTypeForItem(uint i)` accepts `uint` only and the `i` in `Select` seems to use `int`. Can I modify the type of `i` somehow?

Comment: @tzippy: Well you could cast it. But you could also consider changing your `GetTypeForItem` method - while `uint` *sounds* like a good idea, you'll find quite a lot of .NET code is really based around `int`.

Answer (score 13):

```
public int[] type
{
    get
    {
         return Enumerable.Range(0, NumberOfItems).Select(gettypeforitem).ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Update:**
As suggested in comments its better to keep C# naming standards:

```
public int[] Types
{
    get
    {
         return Enumerable.Range(0, NumberOfItems).Select(getTypeForItem).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simplify the select using a method group instead of a lambda. I.e. `Select(gettypeforitem)`

Comment: As we are on C# territory it would be good to not use lower case for public properties. 

Also readonly property instead of method frustrates me. Probably I'm wrong, but I think it breaks property semantics.

So, please, don't teach newbie to do bad things )

Answer (score 3):

Since you know the number of items, you can create an array straight away:

```
int[] _arr = new int[NumberOfItems];
for(uint i=0; i<NumberOfItems;i++)
    _arr[i] = gettypeforitem(i);
return _arr;
```

Or if you don't care about the overhead:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, NumberOfItems).Select(gettypeforitem).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the return type of the property have to be really an array? If not, you can alternatively also use this:

```
public IEnumerable<int> type
{
      get
      {
            for(uint i=0; i<NumberOfItems;i++)
               yield return gettypeforitem(i);
      }
}
```

and then:

```
myObject.type.ToArray();
```